# On iOS7 simulator images shown as blue shadow

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, ios-simulator

This is how app look like on iOS7 iPhone Simulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NMvZ.jpg

And this is how it look like on iOS6 iPhone Simulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Wjl.jpg

So why it is not showing imager but just this blue shadow ?
I am doing screanshots so it is a little bit a problem.

Also on 
This is how app look like on iOS7 iPad Simulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxa9R.jpg

And this is how it look like on iOS6  iPad iPhone Simulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAMMm.jpg

Also it loo like that iOS 6 add white background on imager on iPhone, but not on iPad. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Wjl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAMMm.jpg

On physical devices I have only tested it on "iPhone 4 iOS 6.1" and "iPad Mini iOS 7.1"
And there there is no this blue shadow.

Any idea how to fix it in simulator ?

Comment: Check out the `renderingMode` property on `UIImage`

Comment: use spark inspector and you can find out the reason.

Comment: @Mike I solved the problem, your tip did help. I had to change in storyboard Button Type from System to Custom. And now it is working. In iPad storyboard it was set to this custom, what is strange because I did not do it. I look like Xcode did it automatically for iPad but not for iPhone ??? Put this as answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Shubham did not know about this tool. It look like good stuff, I did not try it now, but I know for future.